# Why won't user input and selection be read correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, debugging

I can't for the life of me understand what I'm doing wrong here.  Using only vanilla JS, I'm trying to check if the user placed a valid number in the text field followed by choosing an option from the dropdown menu.

If they're both invalid, an error should come up.
If age is valid and dropdown menu item is invalid, an error should come up.
If dropdown menu item is invalid and age is valid, an error should come up.

As we speak, if I enter a valid and choose an item from the dropdown menu, I get the `insert a valid number and choose an option from the dropdown!` which's totally wrong.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my HTML:

```
<form>
            <div>
                <label>Number
                    <input type="text" name="number">
                </label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>My Menu
                    <select name="menu">
                        <option value="">---</option>
                        <option value="item1">Item 1</option>
                        <option value="item2">Item 2</option>
                        <option value="item3">Item 3</option>
                    </select>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button class="add">add</button>
            </div>
         </form>
```

Here's my JS:

```
var addButton = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
addButton.type = "button";

var numInput = +document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;

var select = document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].selectedIndex == "0";

function validation() {
    if(numInput < 0 || numInput === 0 || isNaN(numInput) && select) {
        alert("insert a valid number and choose an option from the dropdown!");
    } else {
        alert("valid number accepted!");
    }

    if(select) {
        alert("choose an option from the dropdown!");
    } else {
        alert("dropdown menu option chosen!");
    }
}

addButton.onclick = function() {
    validation();
};
```

Comment: do you realize you are reading the values when the page is rendered? They do not keep updating as the user makes changes. You need to read the values inside of your method.

Comment: @epascarello yes.... I just realized the moment I posted this question, thank you.  It's working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the values to check when you run `validation()`

```
function validation() {
    var numInput = +document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
    var select = document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].selectedIndex == "0";
    if(numInput < 0 || numInput === 0 || isNaN(numInput) && select) {
```